# Intersection with points in aframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

since the point's is just a 3d coordinate. It is very hard to intersect with it by cursor or mouse. But in three.js(here is 
an example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_points.html). The mouse can intersect with points very sensitive. Is there any solution in aframe for this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame has a mouse-based raycaster mode. Have you tried that?

https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/cursor.html#properties_rayorigin

`<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">`

Then add the event listeners and handlers, etc (https://aframe.io/aframe-school/#/10)

Example: http://aframevr.github.io/aframe/examples/showcase/link-traversal